# torch.Tensor manipulation - call methods on sub vectors

Tags: lua, lua-table, torch

I've got a tensor which is a vector with 9 cells, I would like to pull cells 3 to 6 with out looping, like in Matlab.

More Info:

```
th> my_table = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ... 0.9}
-- I create tensor out of it.
th> t_table = torch.Tensor(my_table )
-- I get the vector 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ..., 0.9
-- Now I will get it's mean like this:
th> torch.mean(t_table)
0.5
-- Now I would like to do for example torch.mean on cells 3-6.
th> --<what to write here?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the torch library, but the documentation for [`torch.Tensor`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md) shows that there exist a [`:sub`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-subdim1s-dim1e---dim4s--dim4e) and a [`:select`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-selectdim-index) meta methods as well as a really great [`__index`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor--dim1dim2--or--dim1sdim1e-dim2sdim2e-) method, which supports slicing of a tensor.

You can use one of those to get the tensor for index 3 to 6 and apply `torch.mean` on it.